# Find two real numbers x and y such that x, y, x + y, x^2, y^2, x^2 - y^2, x^3, y^3, x^4, y^4 are all irrational but x^2 + y^2 is rational.

Tags: real-analysis

Find two real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x, y, x + y, x^2 , y^2 ,  x^2 - y^2, x^3, y^3, x^4, y^4$ are all irrational but $x^2 + y^2$ is rational.

What is the approach to solve this problem? It cannot be guess and check, right?

(Shout-outs to CI students. D is for diploma!)

Comment: Hmm...how about $x = \cos 7$ and $y = \sin 7$?

Comment: Thanks, Adriano. I will try it... But I am more interested in the process than in the answer. :D I have no clue how to approach this problem other than guess-and-check.

Comment: If we choose $x$ and $y$ "at random" among the reals, with the additional condition that $x^2+y^2=1$, or $77$, then the other numbers are all irrational with probability $1$.  Pretty good odds!

Answer (score 3):

If we want to avoid transcendentals, use $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$.

The price is that we need to work a little harder to prove the irrationality of $x$, $y$, $x+y$, $x^2$, $y^2$, $x^2-y^2$, $x^3$, $y^3$, $x^4$ and $y^4$. But not much harder, there is a lot of symmetry.

Comment: Even with $\pi$ there is some work for $x+y$ to get the polynomial. Your suggestion does not need more work than that (for example, $x^2-y^2=(x^2+y^2)-2y^2$ is almost immediate.

Answer (score 1):

The idea for me to approaching this would be for $x^2+y^2$ to come out to something really nice, i.e. rational or even integral. So for example, if you set $x=\sqrt{1-\pi/4}$, what is a good value for $y$?